# What is the benefit of using YAML?

Tags: ruby, file, eval, yaml, inspect

When someone mentions the idea of saving information to external files by writing the `inspect` output and loading it via `eval`, I see that many people will criticize that idea and instead recommend using YAML. What is the problem of writing the output of `inspect`, and why is YAML preferrable? For human readability, I think ruby `inspect` or `pp` format is superior to YAML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming nothing overrides `inspect`, of what use is this?:

```
#<Foo:0xa34feb8 @bar="wat">
```

When compared to this:

```
--- !ruby/object:Foo
bar: wat
```

YAML is more likely to produce useful output under non-trivial circumstances. It's also portable, and can be used as a more reliable way of sending serialized data between disparate systems.

Answer (score 4):

Security is the main concern. Because `eval` will run any code passed to it, a malicious hacker could inject code into your data file, and take control of your program. This may not be important for small scripts for yourself, but in a ruby on rails  server, security will be important. Imagine we have the following code:

```
f=File.new("foobar.txt")
f.puts Foo.new.tap {|foo| foo.bar="bork"}.inspect
```

This would, assuming that `Foo` has not overwritten `inspect`, would give something like this:

```
#<Foo:0xff456a5 @bar="bork">
```

Obviously, this is not valid Ruby syntax. Oddly enough, `eval` throws no error, but just returns `nil`. That only makes this a worse idea, as a variable that you expected to be a `Foo` is now just `nil` (The infamous `NoMethodError: undefined method 'bork' for nil:NilClass` error).

The other large problem with this is that of security. Say your code saves data to a file, let's say `foo.txt`, and stores an `inspect`ed hash mapping `bar`s to their respective `baz`es. A different program that needs to know these mappings to plan the FOO convention reads and `eval`s this file. Imagine that this file is somewhere where a hacker could access it (which, when you think about it, is almost anywhere). If these programs are running on a RoR server that also stores all the foo's financial data, the hacker could cause mass chaos. If this hacker injected code into `foo.txt`, that, say, downloaded a malicious virus to the system and installed it, but still left the original program's hash at the end, it would execute unnoticed. Even if you `eval` the data with a `$SAFE=4`, the hacker can still damage the stability of the foo planing program by throwing errors and the like.

All in all, although the `inspect`-`eval` approach works for basic classes such as `Hash`, `String`, `Array`, etc., it depends on the class to give an *exact syntactic representation* of itself. For most, if not all applications it is a bad idea to use `inspect`-`eval`. YAML is preferred because it has a defined syntax for *data*, meaning that executable code mixed in would cause errors, rather than being mindlessly executed. Also, many developers use `inspect` for debugging, and would not expect an object to give a file dump of itself.

The other benefits of YAML are that it serializes complex objects easily. A complex object tree of foos and bars would be easy to do with YAML, but using `inspect` would create huge complication. In the final analysis, this can be thought of as the JSON problem--executable code in data executed because `eval` was used. `inspect` may be fine for small utilities for yourself, but never in production code, or code open to the great mean wide world.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend YAML because:

1. It is easy to understand for us humans, not just a language.
2. It is a standard so it is portable across multiple languages.
3. It supports scalars, arrays, hashes and string and numerics. It also has some cool namespace abilities and aliases so you can reuse definitions and treat data as separate chunks.
4. See #1 and #2 again. Those are important.

Comment: I understand #2, but see my question for #1.